# What's a word for marrying someone of similar status?

Tags: single-word-requests, prefixes

Hypergamy is an action of marrying someone of a higher socio-economic class while hypogamy is doing the same for a person of lower socio-economic class. What is it called, if you marry someone of a similar class?

Answer (score 4):

One word used here is **isogamy**:

> Marriage customs in which the partners are of different social
> statuses (see anisogamy).
>
> In hypergamy, the woman is typically of lower social status than the
> man; hypogamy is the opposite. Isogamy designates marriage between
> social equals.

[[Oxford Reference](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095953889#:%7E:text=Marriage%20customs%20in%20which%20the,See%20also%20marriage%20systems.)]

> - *Besides the two types of hypergamy, isogamy and hypogamy are also sparingly found.*

[Anthrosource: *Hierarchy and Hypergamy* ... R S Khare](https://anthrosource.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1525/aa.1972.74.3.02a00250)

This is not the default sense. As with 'homogamy', there is a sense used in biology.

Answer (score 2):

It is called ***[homogamy](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/homogamy):***

> marriage between people from similar sociological or educational backgrounds.

(Lexico)